# What prevent Cocotron to be crosscompiled on Visual Studio instead of Mac OS X?

Tags: visual-studio, cocoa, macos, frameworks

Seems like Cocotron is a good choice:
http://macdaddyworld.com/2008/10/27/adventures-in-cocotron/

But crosscompilation is on Mac / XCode. What prevents to be able to do the other way round ?

Update: just stumbled upon this news [When would Visual Studio for Mac OS X /Objective C finally released as announced by Steve Ballmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553257/when-would-visual-studio-for-mac-os-x-objective-c-finally-released-as-announced)

Comment: Happy you've found this funny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is technically possible but out of Cocotron's scope. Cocotron works by having code developed for the Mac be compiled targeting Windows. As Apple don't provide SDKs and cross-compilers for Windows, the Cocotron project is **writing** another SDK whose API is compatible with Apple's and uses underlying Windows (or Linux, or Solaris) and auxiliary APIs as needed. The project also provides the cross-compilation toolchain.

Notice that the original intent of Cocotron is to provide a way for **Mac** developers to target their projects at Windows and/or some other Unix-based operating systems.

You want it the other way around. As such, someone would have to provide a suitable cross-compiler toolchain and somehow tell Visual Studio to use that, and link against Cocotron. I can see this happening in two ways: either Windows developers make the effort of adapting toolchains/Cocotron to Visual Studio, or Chris Lloyd is hired to do it. You can always ask him. ;-)

Also, I'm not sure if nib loading works in Cocotron but if (or when) it does, Windows developers would probably want a UI design tool similar to Interface Builder.

Comment: If Chris Lloyd would do so I'm pretty sure he would have much more programmers joining cocotron than today because visual studio fans are in huge numbers :)