# When would Visual Studio for Mac OS X /Objective C finally released as announced by Steve Ballmer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, visual-studio, macos

As I read here http://www.sdtimes.com/MAC_DEVELOPERS_EMBRACE_NET_WITH_VISUAL_OBJECTIVE_C/By_I_B__Phoolen/34234

> The centerpiece of Visual Studio for
>   Mac OS X is Visual Objective-C, a
>   native implementation of Apple’s
>   preferred object-oriented programming
>   language, which is used on both Mac OS
>   X and the iPhone SDK. According to
>   Ballmer, Visual Objective-C will also
>   appear in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for
>   Windows. Applications written in the
>   Smalltalk-inspired language will
>   require only a simple recompile to run
>   on both Mac and Windows 7 systems, he
>   said.

Comment: That... was an April Fools joke. And you just fell hard for it.

Comment: I heard the thud here, even. Oh, wait; that thud was me hitting the floor to roll around laughing when I hit the line about Ballmer getting hoarse.

Comment: Seriously, what the **free**, well **designed**, and **nice** Xcode, Interface Builder... from the Mac development environment could possibly miss compared to vs? Tried both. Mac, ten times.

Comment: @ring0 - ehhh... w/e. "Right tool/Right job" and all.

Comment: OK guys you got me on this one :) I tried XCode clearly it's not as powerfull as Visual Studio as for managing simultaneously multiple solutions and projects, team system etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

April fools' day - I strongly doubt that Microsoft would ever port Visual Studio to run on OS X because of very different technology platforms.

Comment: Why not ? Since Mono did it. And as proof of concept http://code.google.com/p/oscompiler/ which is Objective C for .NET

Comment: @user310291 - For the same reason we'll never see Xcode on Windows.  Why go through the effort of porting a massive project, just to let people use your competitor's OS?

Comment: @user310291 Porting a huge IDE such as Visual Studio is far from the same of porting the compiler. It would be a major investment which wouldn't really make much sense.

Comment: Reading this in 2017 is hilarious.

Comment: Finally they did ;) https://www.visualstudio.com/fr/vs/visual-studio-mac

Comment: @Xorandor - So the compiler itself was ported, the IDE is a fork of Xamarin though with some great added features, and SQL Server itself is ported. Microsoft saw all these comments and took heed. Thank you for your skepticism, it helped push this direction.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it wasn't Steve Balmer making the announcement but [Microsoft stated today (not April Fool's)](http://mashable.com/2015/04/29/visual-studio-code/) that Visual Studio **Code** will run on OS X and Linux. Whether this will actually change the weather forecast for Haddes (or insert culturally appropriate analogy here) is anybody's guess.

Comment: Yes, and we are now multiple iterations into Visual Studio Mac with the ability to deploy to docker containers in Azure in a recent release, it's great seeing something like this which was nobody ever would have believed come to light. It's almost as fun as mentioning SQL Server runs on Linux.